# Running Google Earth Engine Datalab through docker

Tags: docker, google-cloud-datalab, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to install Google Earth Engine Datalab (to use the Python API) in my windows (Home Edition) PC. As I can't install docker as is, I’ve installed Docker Toolbox. Then, I’ve installed the latest image as the instructions in https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install-datalab-local

Everything went fine. In Kitematic I can see that the image is running. It tells me to open the Datalab through http://localhost:8081, but when I open it, nothing comes up. When I click the 'preview' in Kitematic it opens another url (http://192.168.99.100:8081) but doesn’t work either.

To try docker I’ve  installed ‘hello-world-nginx’, and it works fine. As it uses a *server-client* protocol, I assume the problem is with the Earth Engine image. I have also installed it in a Linux PC and worked fine.

When I run

> docker logs 'docker ps -q -l'

```
/website_files/index.html not found.
Copying default index.html...
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2017/08/24 12:17:11 [notice] 6#0: using the "epoll" event method
2017/08/24 12:17:11 [notice] 6#0: nginx/1.4.7
2017/08/24 12:17:11 [notice] 6#0: built by gcc 4.8.3 (OpenWrt/Linaro GCC 4.8-2014.04 r45973)
2017/08/24 12:17:11 [notice] 6#0: OS: Linux 4.4.83-boot2docker
2017/08/24 12:17:11 [notice] 6#0: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2017/08/24 12:17:11 [notice] 6#0: start worker processes
2017/08/24 12:17:11 [notice] 6#0: start worker process 7
192.168.99.1 - - [24/Aug/2017:12:17:11 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 361 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Kitematic/0.17.0 Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Electron/0.35.4 Safari/537.36"
192.168.99.1 - - [24/Aug/2017:12:18:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 361 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36"
2017/08/24 12:18:32 [info] 7#0: *3 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 192.168.99.1, server: 0.0.0.0:80
2017/08/24 12:18:32 [info] 7#0: *2 client 192.168.99.1 closed keepalive connection
2017/08/24 12:18:32 [error] 7#0: *4 open() "/usr/htmlindex.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.99.1, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.99.100:32768", referrer: "http://192.168.99.100:32768/"
192.168.99.1 - - [24/Aug/2017:12:18:32 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 199 "http://192.168.99.100:32768/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36"
2017/08/24 12:18:42 [info] 7#0: *4 client 192.168.99.1 closed keepalive connection
/website_files/index.html found.
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2017/08/24 12:29:13 [notice] 5#0: using the "epoll" event method
2017/08/24 12:29:13 [notice] 5#0: nginx/1.4.7
2017/08/24 12:29:13 [notice] 5#0: built by gcc 4.8.3 (OpenWrt/Linaro GCC 4.8-2014.04 r45973)
2017/08/24 12:29:13 [notice] 5#0: OS: Linux 4.4.83-boot2docker
2017/08/24 12:29:13 [notice] 5#0: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2017/08/24 12:29:13 [notice] 5#0: start worker processes
2017/08/24 12:29:13 [notice] 5#0: start worker process 6
192.168.99.1 - - [24/Aug/2017:12:29:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 361 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Kitematic/0.17.0 Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Electron/0.35.4 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Open the Docker terminal and run `docker logs \`docker ps -q -l\`` This should give you the logs of the container you launched last. See if the logs show you any error?

Comment: there it is @TarunLalwani

Comment: This seems to be your nginx container hello world one. use `docker ps` find the container id for your image and then get logs using `docker logs <ID>`